# Difference between transfer to ethereum account or to smart contract?

Tags: solidity, address.transfer, wallet-transfer, fallback-function

Is there a difference between sending ether to a user account or to a smart contract. E.g.:

```
contract ThisIsAContract{
    function()
        public
        payable
    {}
}
```

Now I call (pseudocode)

`address(0x0).transfer(payout);`

and also

`address(ThisIsAContract.address).transfer(payout);`

Are both okay and do they act the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference is that transactions to non-contracts always cost 21k (unless you have tx data included), whereas transactions to contracts will execute the byte code at that address, which may cost more than 21k. So when you transfer to a contract, you should always do a gas estimate and set the gas amount manually.